# How to bring username show it at Shell with xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

How to bring username show it at Shell with xamarin?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X41fM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can try to set the LoginPage as the MainPage in the App.cs:

```
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new Page1();
    }
```

Then you can set the FlyoutHeader in the AppShell.xaml, such as:

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <Label x:Name="header" />
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>
```

And then you can change AppShell's construction method, such as:

```
public AppShell(string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        header.Text = name;
    }
```

Finally, you can set the App.Current.MainPage as AppShell in the login button's clicked event in the LoginPage, such as:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "";
        App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(name);
    }
```

In addition, you can also try to use mvvm and bind a string variable which is in the viewmodel to the control which you want to show the username.  And then change the variable's value in the button clicked event.

Comment: Your code is working fine. But if it's inside FlyoutHeaderTemplate It cannot be referenced. What can I do?

Comment: I tried many method and it seems we can't get the instance of the `FlyoutHeaderTemplate`. So you may need to use the `Shell.FlyoutHeader`. @IsawaMac